# Web scraping of my Kibana server

Tags: python, elasticsearch, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, kibana

I am running the ELK stack for the log analysis in which kibana is being used as the data visualization.Now I want to extract the some fields from the kibana webpage.
[image]

I want to extract the CU and count field and as you can see I have attached the screenshot of the webpage and corresponding html source code.

Now I have tried to scrap the same webpage using the python and "Beautiful soap" library but there whatever code I am seeing it is different.

Please help.also,
Can you suggest me some other method by which I can extract the required fields?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to make direct request to your elasticsearch for the data you need.

You can see the query executed by visualization if you go to Dashboard and click the arrow in the bottom left corner and select `Request` tab:

[image: Kibana visualization in dashboard]